# How should I connect my new motion-detecting light switch?

Tags: wiring, switch, light-fixture

I bought a [Legrand RRW600U](http://www.legrand.us/radiant/products/switches/rrw600utc.aspx) motion-detecting light switch and I could use some help wiring it to my bathroom light.  It's a renovation so I have complete access to the ceiling, wall, and floor framing.

The switch has three wires in the back (black, red, and yellow) and a single green(ish) screw.  The bathroom light has three wires:  black, white, and bare copper.  I am installing new, 14/2 non-metallic sheathed cable to connect the service panel to the switch to the light.

Both the [printed instructions](http://www.legrand.us/-/media/brands/radiant/resources/installation-instructions/radiant%20120v%20single%20pole%20occupancy%20sensor.ashx) and the only YouTube video I could find seem to assume that the electrical circuit passes through the light before terminating in the switch.  I would like my circuit to pass through the switch and terminate in the light.

How would I wire the switch to the light in that setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned up the diagram from the directions:

[image]

- Neutral passes through (White to white wire)
- Line (Black) connects to black on the switch
- Red from the switch connects to black wire to the light
- Yellow from the switch is not connected, just capped off with a wire nut
- Ground everything

  - Green wire on switch
  - Ground must be connected to ground screw on all junction boxes
  - Ground on all wires also connected together

Comment: Great diagram, just one question.  There is no green wire coming from the switch -- just black, red, and yellow wires.  There is a green screw on the side of the switch.  How are the ground wires configured in that case?  (Oh, and:  the box housing the switch is plastic and has no grounding screw.)

Comment: Always a good sign when the manual is wrong.. Anyway, you just need to connect a bare wire to the screw, and then to the rest of the ground wires. You can skip the ground in the box since it's plastic and doesn't have a screw.

Answer (score 0):

Run cable from the panel to the switch and another from the switch to the light. Connect the supply cable black to the switch's black wire with a wirenut. Connect the light cable's black wire to the red wire with a wirenut. Connect together the white wires with a wirenut , not connecting to the switch. Connect together the the green wires along with a separate short piece of green or bare wire with a wirenut. This short wire goes to the green screw. The yellow wire is not connected; cover the end with a wirenut.

At the light, connect black to black, white to white and green to ground.

Answer (score 0):

On most all household type switches (domestic switches) used in 120/240 volt scenarios, the black lead at the switch is almost always your common hot feed and the red would be used for the switchleg connection going to your light fixture